# Install an UWP application (and eventually run it) by command-line

Tags: win-universal-app

I have two differents problematics that i solved in a certain way but i want to know if there is a better way to do it.
First, i get an UWP application package, built with Visual Studio 2015 that i wan't to install in a lumia 950 (windows 10). For this, i will use the regular winappdeploycmd tool, provided with the windows kits (in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86 : here is the documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/mt203806.aspx)

Currently, i succeeded to install it by using this commandline and by plugging the device on the build machine by USB :

> WinAppDeployCmd.exe install -file myfile.appx -d mydependency.appx -ip 127.0.0.1

But, if you read properly the documentation, it should be possible to run it by using the wifi network, thus, i un-plugged the device and connected it to the wifi network, i checked this by using :

```
> WinAppDeployCmd.exe devices
Windows App Deployment Tool
Version 10.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Discovering devices...
IP Address      GUID                                    Model/Name
192.168.1.4     00000015-fccc-e26c-0000-000000000000    Windows-phone1
```

It looks nice, my build machine is on 192.168.1.1

Then i try :

```
> WinAppDeployCmd.exe install -file myfile.appx -d mydependency.appx -ip 192.168.1.4
Windows App Deployment Tool
Version 10.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Opening connection to device at '192.168.1.4'.

Access denied while connecting to the remote device.
Please retry the command with the "-pin" option and a valid pin as shown in the device settings.
The pin is a one time requirement to establish a pairing relationship with the device.
```

(since my build machine is already paired with the device : i did it by going into the device iot portal on https://192.168.1.4 and i can clearly read on the device that the number of paired machine is 1)

But i try to use the pin parameter :

```
> WinAppDeployCmd.exe install -file myfile.appx -d mydependency.appx -ip 192.168.1.4 -pin ABCDEF
Windows App Deployment Tool
Version 10.0.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Opening connection to device at '192.168.1.4'.

Access denied while connecting to the remote device.
Please retry the command with the "-pin" option and a valid pin as shown in the device settings.
The pin is a one time requirement to establish a pairing relationship with the device.
```

Damned same answer... I have to precise here that i checked by disabling all the firewalls, by using another network in a different place, by changing the device for a lumia 640, by changing the build machine and even by changing the ip parameter by the guid one... nothing works !

Also, when i check on internet, what i can find is more or less different reproductions of the microsoft documentation but without any screenshot or logs; the only people who have clearly succeeded to do this operation have done it by using the usb cable.

If someone is able to explain me how this works, i would be very grateful.

***Additional question:*** If someone has a solution to run the application once installed by using a command-line, it could be great too ! I have an idea for doing it by using a tricky way (by simulating a click on the run button on the iot portal interface, did not try for now, but it should be possible) but it should be better to do it in a regular way...

Hope that i have been clear enough.